# How to read a ISO14443 typeB card which is not compliant with 14443-4 through an Android NFC phone?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm working on an android application, my goal is to read a ISO14443 type B card. The card is only compliant with ISO14443B-1,-2,-3, but not -4.

Our test smart phone(Samsung N7100,android version 4.1.2) can only detect the existence of the card, but can not connect to it. When we put the card near the NFC antenna of the phone, the phone will keep beeping and never stop. And also, it seems that there's no NFC intent created.

As the card is not compliant with ISO14443-4, so the android NFC discover and dispatch mechanism dose not work. My question is, can I bypass the mechanism and access the NFC low level API to send my own card discovery and APDU commands through the NFC adapter of the phone?

Comment: Have you tried the [foreground dispatch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) mode ?